# Alternatives to breadth-first-search in 3D grid cluster detection?

Tags: algorithms, c, computer-vision, search

I've got a question about a good way to find the quickest algorithm for my problem:

**problem:**
I've got a 3D cubical grid containing voxels that are either 1 or 0. It is stored as a flattened array. If multiple 1-voxels are neighboring each other, they form a cluster together.
I want to detect clusters smaller than a given size (n).

**current solution (slow):**

For each 1-voxel, I'm doing a breadth first search to find how many neighbors it has, and how many neighbors the neighbors have, etc, until reaching a certain amount of neighbors (n).

this is horribly slow when setting n to my preferred amount n>50, because the total cube edge size is 64

Any different ways to do this that are not breadth first search? Everything is open: could even be something from computer vision like 3d pooling or whatever, but I'm a little stuck. Or am I better off trying to optimize my current approach? If interested, I posted [my c# code in code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237626/detecting-isolated-voxel-blob-in-3d-cube-with-breadth-first-search)

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: I know that octrees are sometimes used for this purpose but unfortunately I am not aware of any non-industrial documents about it.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas sounds interesting and relevant. Will do some research and post findings here if any